# Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied) (running as sudo)

Tags: permissions, sudo, lubuntu

I am trying to install Veeam Agent on a fresh Lubuntu 20.04 installation. I've downloaded the latest Veeam package, but get this when I try to install:

```
 ~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i ./veeam-release* && apt-get update
 (Reading database ... 268018 files and directories currently installed.)
 Preparing to unpack .../veeam-release-deb_1.0.8_amd64.deb ...
 Unpacking veeam-release-deb (1.0.8) over (1.0.8) ...
 Setting up veeam-release-deb (1.0.8) ...
 Reading package lists... Done
 E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
 E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
 W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
 W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

I've tried:

- Rebooting
- "sudo su" then repeating the process
- sudo apt-get update

Any ideas??

Comment: `sudo dpkg -i ./veeam-release* && apt-get update` (from a non-root shell) runs `dpkg -i ./veeam-release*` as root, but runs `apt-get update` as your unprivileged user